# Why are more columns on one labels in Angular ChartJS?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, charts, chart.js

I would like to create bar chart in Chart.js and shows which is the longest movie by category.
So I have a map which contain the title and length of the longest movie by category.
example:
0: {"Intouchables" => "107"} (from comedy)
1: {"The Devil's Advocate" => "144"} (from thriller)
I put these two data separately in an array:

```
this.keys = Array.from(this.map.keys());
this.values = Array.from(this.map.values());
```

In bar chart I want title as label, length as data and category as labels.

I tried this:

```
createDiagram(){

    this. barChartOptions = {
      scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
      responsive: true
    };

    this.barChartLabels = ['Comedy', 'Thriller'];
    this. barChartType = 'bar';
    this. barChartLegend = true;

    this.barChartData = [
      {data: [this.values[0]], label: this.keys[0]},
      {data: [this.values[1]], label: this.keys[1]}
    ];
  }
```

html code:

```
<button (click)="createDiagram()">Create</button>
<div>
  <div style="display: block">
      <canvas baseChart
              [datasets]="barChartData"
              [labels]="barChartLabels"
              [options]="barChartOptions"
              [legend]="barChartLegend"
              [chartType]="barChartType"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

and I get this bar chart:
[image]

So why are both columns on a comedy?
How can I do  blue come up on  thriller ?

Comment: Can u create stackblitz with your dummy data which comes from api ?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gipqmb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zbiufy

You have two categories. So for every input u need to add two values. Then for two color, U can make fist item's second value 0 and second item's first value 0 then u can get what u want.

```
 this.barChartData = [
          {data: [this.values[0],0], label: this.keys[0]},
          {data: [0,this.values[1]], label: this.keys[1]}
        ];
```